# requests_html render method continues to result in timeout

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html, pyppeteer

I'm not sure if it's the setting of my computer (Windows 7, Python3.8, just recently installed requests_html), but no matter which site I choose, the `render` method is resulting in `timeout error`
I have played around with timeout parameter, but no luck.

```
import os
import sys
import requests_html
import requests
import pyppeteer



def get_request(url, render = False):

    session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
    res = session.get(url)

    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise('Dead link')

    if render:
        res.html.render(sleep = 2, timeout = 20)

    return res, session


def test_render():
    url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/'
    res, session = get_request(url, render = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this and it prefectly works:

```
import os
import sys
import requests_html
import requests
import pyppeteer



def get_request(url, render = False):

    session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
    res = session.get(url)

    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise('Dead link')

    if render:
        res.html.render(sleep = 2, timeout = 20)

    return res, session


def test_render():
    url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/'
    res, session = get_request(url, render = True)

#test_render()
[res, session]= get_request('https://www.yahoo.com/', render=True)
print(res.text)
```

check your settings because i didnt change anything just debugged

Comment: Thank you. What settings should I be looking for? I'm not sure exactly what to check for. I know Chromium is working because I see it under task manager.

Comment: try to handle the timeout errors check this:
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53010/requests.Timeout